# How to add more input tag value with JavaScript for Forms when submitting

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a page which may has about more than 1 form like below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1">
            <input type="text" name="fname1" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <form id="form2">
            <input type="text"  name="fname2"/>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <form id="form3">
            <input type="text" name="fname3" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

        <script>
             var formsx = document.forms.length; 
             for (i= 0; i < formsx; i++) {
                 form = document.forms[i];
                 form.addEventListener("submit", function(evt){
               /// alert("form action");
               });
             }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to add one hidden value () whenever user submits form with Classic Javascript.  If any of form submit, the new hidden value should be added. So at the backend, the POST request will have two "name" and "hidden" parameters values instead of one according to above script. I just want to code with JavaScript only. Please let me know how can I do that, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `document.createElement` and `appendChild`:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(evt){
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  input.setAttribute("name", newName);
  input.setAttribute("value", "value");
  form.appendChild(input);
  return true;
});
```

Comment: note originally I had document.getElementById("form1").appendChild. Since you already have a handle on the form in question, the variable "form" should work as well.

Comment: When i do with that, it does do at all. the new parameter doesn't pass to form.